# Javascript code to make YouTube progress bar come back

Tags: javascript, youtube

I found this code [on some website](https://asapguide.com/hide-youtube-bar/#:%7E:text=javascript%3A(function()%7Bvar,450px)%20100vw%2C%20450px%22%3E), which I can set as a bookmark to make the progress bar on YouTube go away.

What would the reverse of this code be so I can set that as a bookmark too, so I can make the progress bar come back? Other than reloading the page.

Thanks!

```
javascript:(function(){var goaway=".ytp-chrome-top,.ytp-chrome-bottom{display:none;}";if("\v"=="v"){document.createStyleSheet().cssText=goaway}else{var tag=document.createElement("style");tag.type="text/css";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);tag[(typeof document.body.style.WebkitAppearance=="string")?"innerText":"innerHTML"]=goaway}})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will show/hide the progress bar

```
javascript:document.querySelectorAll(".ytp-chrome-top,.ytp-chrome-bottom").forEach(i=>i.style.display=i.style.display=="inherit"?"none":"inherit");
```

to make the code shorter, at first you need to click it twice to hide, then once to show/hide

Comment: You're welcome, dont forget to mark the answer as correct.